# Is there a way to pass 'exact' numerical arguments in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to input 'exact' numerical values (instead of decimal approximations) as arguments—for coordinates, for example?

I.e., inserting somthing like 2/3 instead of 0.666, or √3 instead of 1.728, etc. in coordinates.

Comment: Should be possible with `\pgfmathparse`...

Comment: You do not even need `\pgfmathparse`, just try something like `\draw(0,0) -- ({sqrt(8)},4);` (note the `{` `}` brackets around  `sqrt(8)`).

Comment: @marmot doesn't work for fractions (I am writing `(120:{4/9}cm)`). Is there another way to write "to-be-evaluated" fractions? Or should I use the typesetting `\frac`?

Comment: Don't use `\frac` (unless you want to see a nice error message ;-) ! And please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Most likely something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: The “exact” values would be transformed into floating point numbers anyway.

Comment: @egreg I know, but just so I don't have to do the computing

Comment: whenever you need a dimension in the coordinate you can multiply with a unit dimension`(120:4/9*1cm))`

Comment: @percusse Do you want to write an answer? (I was about to do that, but now I see your comment.)

Comment: @marmot No problem I rarely have access to TeX these days.So I'm mostly commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions and so on in coordinates as long as you put them in curly brackets and, as pointed out by @percusse, use multiplication signs when you want to use (different) units. This forum is full of examples, and here is yet another one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--({sqrt(2)},{sqrt(3)});
\draw[red](0,0)--(120:{(4/9)*1cm+sqrt(72)*1pt});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, you can mix units. Internally, Ti*k*Z uses points.